# Weird symbols in command line - RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When i use rails on Windows i get a bunch of strange literals besides actual text, like   "[33m.2", "[32m➝*...text...[0m"   and etc. Is there any way to get rid of them and how do you call them?

```
Pending:
←[33m  User should require a name←[0m
←[36m    # Not yet implemented←[0m
←[36m    # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:13←[0m
```

Comment: Those are terminal control escape sequences. Back in the dos days you needed to have ANSI.SYS loaded to allow the prompt to produce colored text, and those escape sequences were how you did things.

Answer (score 1):

Those characters are used to display colors in your command prompt. A way to add those colors in Windows:

- download [Ansicon](http://adoxa.110mb.com/ansicon/)
- extract the correct folder on your computer (x86 if you have a 32-bit, x64 if 64-bit)
- from your command prompt:

> cd path/to/the/folder/you/extracted/
>
> ansicon -i

That will install ansicon permanently to your computer (uninstall procedure in the readme).

- You now have colours in your command prompt and those "weird" symbols will go away.